# Multiples execute to SQL Server From Web-Service

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, web-services

I working on a VB.NET web-service Project that access a Microsoft SQL Server.

Every time a user accesses the web-service, it executes a SQL function.

If the web-service is waiting for a response from the SQL which is executing a fill command, and another user connects to the web-service which is trying to execute a different call to the SQL, it has to wait till the first call will end.

Here is a sample code for the initial SQL connection:

```
Dim tmpCnn As New SqlConnection
tmpCnn.ConnectionString = new String("Server=SQLServer002; User Id=****; Password=****; Database=Reports; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Application Name=WebService; Connect Timeout=120; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;")
tmpCnn.Open()
```

Here is the sample for every SQL call’s fill exce:

```
Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand 
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
sqlCmd.Connection = tmpCnn
Dim num As Integer = 1234
sqlCmd.CommandText = " exec  [WCF].[get_rep] " & num

Dim sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter
sqlDA.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
sqlDA.Fill(ds)
```

Our project requirement is that the second user will not have to wait for the first user’s call to finish executing. Also, our project’s requirement is that the web-service will use only one connection to the SQL for all calls.

How can we solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Do not use a single global connection. Every call to the web service should instantiate its own LOCAL connection instance and thus none will be blocked. Let the [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) do its magic.

Comment: Let the connection pooling do its magic. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use NOLOCK in your query. For example,

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
FROM dbo.person p WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN dbo.employee e WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON e.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE p.person_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I will put my comment here :

It is not possible to achieve this with only one connection as a single connection can't execute multiple query at the same time. Consider having multiple connection. SQL server have a really high limit of number of connection anyway. This way you will be able to execute multiple query at the same time.